# Cryptographic Attacks

Tags: attack

I've been asked to write some course materials on cryptography and included in the objectives are some vulnerabilities/attacks. Most of these I have nailed but there are three that I don't seem to be able to find any info on:

- Version spoofing attack (possibly the same as version rollback attack which I have written about)
- Backtrack attack
- Reverse protocol attack (I found one website that mentions this but not what it actually is)

Can anyone shed any light on them?

Comment: I don't know about these attacks, but if you want to share your course materials, I would be very interested !